# Pandas IS IN - as a Oracle SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
SELECT
    testtable1.id,
        CASE
            WHEN (testtable1.tn_id IN
        SELECT
            b."customer_id"
        FROM
            cu.customer b)
         THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
    END) BLACKLIST
FROM
    testschema.testtable1
```

It should check if the value is found in the other table. And then give a output "Yes" or "No" if its found or not.
I want to do this for conditions so there will be multiple "OR".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options to do it.
Sample data:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (   Select 'A1' "ID", 1 "TN_ID", 'C' "STATUS" From Dual Union All
            Select 'A2' "ID", 2 "TN_ID", 'A' "STATUS" From Dual Union All
            Select 'A3' "ID", 3 "TN_ID", 'B' "STATUS" From Dual Union All
            Select 'A4' "ID", 4 "TN_ID", 'B' "STATUS" From Dual Union All
            Select 'A5' "ID", 5 "TN_ID", 'A' "STATUS" From Dual 
        ),
    cust AS
        (   Select 1 "CUSTOMER_ID", 'Name 1' "CUSTOMER_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "CUSTOMER_ID", 'Name 3' "CUSTOMER_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 4 "CUSTOMER_ID", 'Name 4' "CUSTOMER_NAME" From Dual 
        )
```

1. your SQL (corrected a bit):

```sql
SELECT  t.id,
        CASE    WHEN t.tn_id IN( SELECT CUSTOMER_ID FROM cust ) THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
        END "BLACKLIST"
FROM    tbl t
```

2. using LEFT JOIN

```sql
SELECT    t.ID, CASE Nvl(c.CUSTOMER_ID, 0) WHEN 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END "BLACKLIST"
FROM      tbl t
LEFT JOIN cust c ON(c.CUSTOMER_ID = t.TN_ID)
ORDER BY  t.ID
```

3. using EXISTS

```sql
SELECT    t.ID, CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT CUSTOMER_ID FROM cust WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = t.TN_ID) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END "BLACKLIST"
FROM      tbl t
ORDER BY  t.ID
```

All three returns the same:

```sql
ID BLACKLIST
-- ---------
A1 Yes       
A2 No        
A3 Yes       
A4 Yes       
A5 No
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrong usage of parenthesis; should be

```
SELECT testtable1.id,
       CASE
          WHEN testtable1.tn_id IN (SELECT b."customer_id" FROM cu.customer b)
          THEN 'Yes'
          ELSE 'No'
       END blacklist
  FROM testschema.testtable1
```

---

I don't know what you meant to say by

> I want to do this for conditions so there will be multiple "OR"

Answer (score 2):

Or, the same could be written as:

```
SELECT testtable1.id,
   CASE
      WHEN exists (SELECT 1 FROM cu.customer b
        where b.customer_id=testtable1.tn_id)
      THEN 'Yes'
      ELSE 'No'
   END blacklist
FROM testschema.testtable1
```

And I'd avoid double quoting column names and table names, that is unless those columns and tables have been created in Oracle to be case-sensitive by double quoting the name in the create DDL. Unless object names are not double quoted on creation, Oracle has them in the data dictionary as uppercase.